# Fluid simulation gone

Tags: fluid-simulation

Have a blender file where I've added a quick liquid. Played animation [hit space], works. Resized one object, no animation anymore. Undoing not helping. Adding a cube, adding quick fluid, no animation.

The blue particles don't even appear in the liquid domain, only if I create a new blend file from scratch.

I have not the slightest clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you please give a pic of the problem or even the .blend file along with what version you are using?

Comment: or provide your blend file...